# How do I find the master IP on Docker Desktop Kubernetes Cluster?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I am using Docker Desktop on Windows and have created a local Kubernetes cluster. I've been following this  ([quick start guide](https://blog.sourcerer.io/a-kubernetes-quick-start-for-people-who-know-just-enough-about-docker-to-get-by-71c5933b4633#8787)) and am running into issues identifying my external IP. When creating a service I'm supposed to list the "master server's IP address".

I've identified the master node `kubectl get node`:

```
NAME             STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
docker-desktop   Ready    master   11m   v1.14.7
```

Then used `kubectl describe node docker-desktop`...but an external IP is not listed anywhere.

Where can I find this value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following command so you can see more information about the nodes.

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide
```

or

```
kubectl get nodes -o json
```

You'll be able to see the internal-ip and external-ip.

Pd: In my cluster, the internal-ip works as external-ip, even tho the external-ip is listed as none.